# weird C++ behavior on reallocating object

Tags: c++

I'm experiencing some unusual behavior in C++ that I'd like to understand more. I have a class `Instrument` with a pure virtual function `play`. The classes `Flute` and `Trumpet` inherit from `Instrument` and implement `play`. `Trumpet` has an additional method `toggleMute` which `Flute` does not.

Sorry about just including a link to the Gist before. Here's the complete code:

```
class Instrument
{
public:
  virtual void play() = 0;
};

class Flute : public Instrument
{
public:
  Flute() {};
  void play();
};

class Trumpet : public Instrument
{
protected:
  bool muted;
public:
  Trumpet() {muted = false;};
  void play();
  void toggleMute();
};


void Flute::play()
{
  std::cout << "Dude, play Jethro Tull!" << std::endl;
}

void Trumpet::play()
{
  if (muted) {
    std::cout << "Beep" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Honk" << std::endl;
  }
}

void Trumpet::toggleMute()
{
  muted = muted xor true;
  if (muted) {
    std::cout << "Mute on!" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Mute off!" << std::endl;
  }
}

void transmogrify(Instrument* instrument)
{
  if (instrument) {
    delete instrument;
    instrument = new Flute();
  }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Trumpet *horn = new Trumpet();

  horn->play();
  horn->toggleMute();
  horn->play();
  horn->toggleMute();
  horn->play();

  std::cout << std::endl;

  transmogrify(horn);

  horn->play();
  horn->toggleMute();
  horn->play();
  horn->toggleMute();
  horn->play();

  return 0;
}
```

In another language that I'm learning, this kind of behavior is illegal. If I have a function that takes in an `Instrument*`, I can't pass it an object that's declared as a `Trumpet*` precisely because the language designers wanted to avoid this sort of weirdness. Unfortunately that means there are certain designs that I can't implement which would make my life a lot easier; all told, I prefer the C++'s permissiveness even if some bizarre stuff can happen from time to time.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, instead of a link to the code.

Comment: You haven't included near enough code to fully understand what you are saying.

Comment: Bad coding style and you need to pass a `Instrument*&` to keep it bad and make it work

Comment: you get UB for deleting a pointer to a base class with no virtual destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's going on here? Is this just run-of-the-mill undefined
>   behavior?

What's happening is that transmogrify() is deleting the object that was passed in to the function, then creating a new Flute object, assigning it to a local parameter variable (instrument), which is then lost forever when the function returns.  So you've got a memory leak, and likely undefined behavior in the calling code, if the calling code later tries to dereference the (now dangling) pointer they passed in.

To get the behavior you're looking for, you should pass the pointer by reference instead:

```
void transmogrify(Instrument * & instrument)
```

... that way the caller's pointer will be modified to point to the new Flute object after the function returned.

Comment: this won't fix the code linked to, you'd see the pointer's type was `Trumpet*` which shouldn't be made to point to memory allocated for a flute after the call.

Comment: @rpattiso Uhm what? We don't see such from the OP's question (the link doesn't count!).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ fair enough.

Comment: While @rpattiso is correct in that this didn't fix the code, I understand what's wrong with it now. You'd think that I would understand call-by-reference/value by now. D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

You haven't included enough code to fully understand the issue. But the method you posted is very problematic, and so I'll address that.

It takes a pointer as an argument. The code then deletes what the pointer points to and assigns it a new value.

The problem is that this method receives a copy of the pointer. And so the caller still has the old pointer, which now points to an object that has been deleted. And if the caller uses that pointer, it would be accessing memory no longer owned by the app.

Answer (score 1):

`transmogrify` doesn't take its argument by reference (or even a pointer to pointer) so while it can free the passed in value, it can't return a new one. The caller still has the old pointer which now points to deleted memory. Using it is undefined behavior (which means it may still appear to work).

Answer (score -1):

So, the "contract" of this function says it will take an `Instrument` and is allowed to do anything it wants to it (because `const` was not used anywhere in the function signature).  So you have a pointer to a specific something (Trumpet) and pass it into a function that don't guarantee to not mess with it.  The object that you had a pointer to gets deleted <strike>and replaced with something</strike>.  And as long as that something is of type `Instrument` then the function has not broken it's contract.

Out of curiosity, what would you be trying to do with this pattern?

Comment: _"The object that you had a pointer to gets deleted and replaced with something."_ Nope, it doesn't.

Comment: My apologies, that was worded incorrectly.   It does not get "replaced", a new space has been created for the new object and he now has a pointer to free'ed memory.